# initializer_list assignment overloading

Tags: c++

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
#include <initializer_list>

class IntArray {
    unsigned mLength = 0;
    int *mData = nullptr;

public:
    IntArray(unsigned length) : mLength(length) { mData = new int[length]; }
    ~IntArray() { delete[] this->mData; }
    IntArray(const std::initializer_list<int> &list) : IntArray(list.size()) {
        int count = 0;
        for (auto &e : list) {
            mData[count] = e;
            ++count;
        }
    }

    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, IntArray &arr) {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < arr.mLength; ++i) {
            os << arr.mData[i] << " ";
        }
        os << endl;
        return os;
    }

    //=operator
    IntArray &operator=(const std::initializer_list<int> &array) {
        delete[] mData;
        mLength = array.size();
        if (mData != nullptr) {
            // mData = new int[mLength+1];
            cout << "mLength is " << mLength << endl;
            mData = new int[mLength];
            int i{};
            for (auto &e : array) {
                mData[i++] = e;
                // There's a buffer overrun due to this line
                // so i change
                // mData = new int[mLength]; to mData = new int[mLength+1];
                // Is this bad?
                // Let me know if there's another better way.
            }
        } else {
            mData = nullptr;
        }
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {
    IntArray intArray = {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20};
    intArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    cout << intArray << endl;
}
```

buffer overrun problem keep bodering me.. coding masters
mData[i++] = e;
There's a buffer overrun due to this line
It's more than the index of the array, right?
so i change
this linemData = new int[mLength];
to mData = new int[mLength+1];
Is this bad?
Let me know if there's another better way.
plzplz
coding is so hard...
r u guys are all genius??

Comment: What leads you to believe there's a buffer overrun error in this code? When I compile and run it as-is, it prints out the numbers from 1 to 10, which it what I would intuitively expect from that `main` function.

Comment: If you compile it in the visual studio, it comes out like that.

Comment: Please put the exact error message in the question. I don't see any buffer overrun here.

Comment: Visual Studio is pretty well known for its false positives regarding these matters. Does the issue persist if you tone down the cleverness and write `mData[i] = e; i++;`?

Comment: The "better" way would be `std::copy(array.begin(), array.end(), mData);`. (And not using the name "array" for things that are definitely not arrays.)

Comment: Also, I would reccomend to use `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` type for  `mData` instead of plain pointer. And I hope you know that there exists class `std::vector` which doing what you try to achieve...

Comment: The `if (mData != nullptr)` condition looks strange - why would you not want to copy the argument if that condition is false? (You also do `mData = nullptr;` exactly when `mData` already is null...)

Comment: yes i know I'm studying, so they told me to make one.

Answer (score -1):

Your code runs perfectly on clang, gcc and msvc. There is no issue with what you're referring to whatsoever, however, I want to point out to something in the `IntArray &operator=(const std::initializer_list<int> &array);`, the first line of this method is `delete[] mData;` which may cause some undefined behavior if `mData` was `nullptr`, so change it to  `if(mData) delete[] mData;`, the `else{}` statement doesn't run so I'd suggest you change change it to something like this

```
IntArray &operator=(const std::initializer_list<int> &array) {
    if(mData) delete[] mData;
    mLength = array.size();
    cout << "mLength is " << mLength << endl;
    mData = new int[mLength];
    int i{};
    for (auto &e : array) {
        mData[i++] = e;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

This is a possible implementation of it

Comment: "the first line of this method is delete[] mData; which may cause some undefined behavior if mData was nullptr" is false.

Comment: Deleting a nullptr is fine - nothing happens.

Comment: i had some issues with deleting nullptr before so i'd suggest to avoid it

Comment: Quote from standard: *"The value of the first argument supplied to a deallocation function may be a null pointer value; if so, and if the deallocation function is one supplied in the standard library, the call has no effect."* If you have any problems that mean you have not compliant compiler, or you use non-standard deallocation function and should check for `nullptr`.